# Dup2() usage and output redirection

Tags: linux, stdin, system-calls, file-descriptor, dup2

I'm trying to redirect the output of a process to the `stdin` of another process. This is done by `dup2()`. My question is: do `stdin` and `stdout` go back to their `place(0,1)` after function terminates, or do i have to do something like `savestdin = dup(0)`. More clearly, after the function for one command terminates, at the second call are `stdin` and `stdout` on their supposed position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your `stdout` to go to a `fork`ed process' `stdin`, you'll need to use a combination of `pipe` and `dup`. Haven't tested it but it should give you some ideas hopefully:

```c
int my_pipe[2];

pipe(my_pipe); // my_pipe[0] is write end
               // my_pipe[1] is read end

// Now we need to replace stdout with the fd from the write end
// And stdin of the target process with the fd from the read end

// First make a copy of stdout
int stdout_copy = dup(1);

// Now replace stdout
dup2(my_pipe[0], 1);

// Make the child proccess
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    // Replace stdin
    dup2(my_pipe[1], 0);
    execv(....); // run the child program
    exit(1); // error
}
int ret;
waitpid(pid, &ret, 0);

// Restore stdout
dup2(stdout_copy, 1);
close(stdout_copy);

close(my_pipe[0]);
close(my_pipe[1]);
```

So to answer your question, when you use `dup2()` to replace `0` and `1`, they will not be restored to the terminal unless you save the original file descriptor with `dup()` and manually restore it with `dup2()`.